# Get attribute values with JQuery issue (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in..)

Tags: jquery, attributes

I am trying to get attributes values with JQuery but I am getting error which is: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in PROD

I saw some advises which are about the downgrade JQuery version to 1.10.xx but I am getting this error with all versions of JQuery.

Do you any advise?

Thanks in advance..

My code is below:

```
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <input test="PROD" value="2" type="text">
    <input test="DEV"  value="3" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="Write It" onclick="writeIt()"/>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function writeIt() {
    $.each($('input').attr('test'), function () {
        var testdata = $(this).attr('test');
        //$(this).val(testdata);
        console.log(testdata);
    });

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
<script>
function writeIt() {
    $('input:not([type="button"])').each(function () {
        var testdata = $(this).attr('test');
        //$(this).val(testdata);
        console.log(testdata);
    });

}
</script>
```

**Demo**

```js
function writeIt() {
    $('input:not([type="button"])').each(function () {
       var testdata = $(this).attr('test');
       //$(this).val(testdata);
       console.log(testdata);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input test="PROD" value="2" type="text">
<input test="DEV"  value="3" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Write It" onclick="writeIt()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer. After your answer, I've change my code as    `code`  $("input[test]").each(function () {
        var testdata = $(this).attr('test');
        //$(this).val(testdata);
        console.log(testdata);
    }); `code` and it works properly. Can you please explain me what is the wrong stuff in my code?

Comment: @Grcn the wrong way you use .each through $('input').attr('test') .. and you need objects to loop through and then get attr() from it .. you can also try  $.each($("input[test]"))..  your $("input[test]") selector is very good as well .. Good Luck to you :)

Comment: Thank you very much again :) @Mohamed